# cURL retrieving CSV file

Tags: php, curl, csv, file-transfer

My hosting company must have changed their server or something, I've had this code running flawlessly for 8-10 years..YEARS!.. and today its stopped. Im wondering if the use of cURL today has changed much from when I wrote this 8-10 years ago.. please help. It grabs the csv and continues for a very very long time to get the file.. i exit the browser after 20 mins.. should and used to only take maybe 25 seconds tops. The first line below was also an issue.. somehow on any other server it showed the correct 3 months back date.. on my server my sites hosted on.. it shows 1969.. so at first I assumed the date trying to get data from 1969 was the lagg/holdup.. but when I fixed this to new code it still lags.

```
//$newdates = date("Ymd",strtotime(date('Ymj')) - (60 * 24 * 60 * 60));
// the above for some reason doesnt work anymore gives the 1969 date.. so below fixed

$newdates = date("Ymd", strtotime("-3 months")); 
$tm = "http://123.theserver.net/data/sel_data=*&query_str=lud>'$newdates'&dl_type=file&send_done=no&e=.csv"; 
$ch = curl_init($tm);  
$fp = fopen("/home/sites/www.mydomain.com/mx/data.csv", 'w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
fclose($fp);
```

Kinda frusterated cause the hosting co says they havent changed anything..and there 2000 miles away,  so is there newer updated code Im missing here?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Is Curl still enabled? `var_dump(curl_version());`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$newdates = date("Ymd", strtotime("-3 months"));    
$url_init = "http://123.theserver.net/data/sel_data=*&query_str=lud>'$newdates'&dl_type=file&send_done=no&e=.csv";

$ch = curl_init($url_init);

    if (!$ch) die ("Curl not loaded");

$fp = fopen("/home/sites/www.mydomain.com/mx/data.csv", 'w'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if( ! $tmp = curl_exec($ch))
{
   echo curl_error($ch);
} 

else
{

header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$start.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $tmp;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This mean that curl grab an XML file or it's parsed as XML, do `var_dump($tmp);` to grab an data.

Comment: Add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Put `var_dump($tmp);` to see an data, your data is parsed but XML based because you get and "Resource id #3" that means you are receiving XML data as Object. So you need parsing a data as XML `$tmp->data["some_info"]["array"][....];` I don+t know how your exactly is your result because you aren't dump a data from result of CURL(); on `var_dump($tmp)`.

Comment: You know, are you sure? Try dump a data.

Comment: Its just data with , 's    so the writing to the csv file is the lagg. Ok it works, it all works it just times out.. 1/4 of the file gets inputed.. so is it my server? (Sammitch go find something to do) If I take the link in the code and put say 20121201 in there and put it into my browser and hit send I get a popup to download the file .. in csv format.. this takes 3 seconds to obtain. So it is in fact my hosting right?!?

Comment: Yep, it's might be. I will check out for error_log to see what's occurred. If no one errors show this is on the hosting/server provider. If server is upgraded and or is in maintenance that could be stopped to working PHP app or it make an a mess.

Comment: Im kinda confused cause you say XML, but they gave me this link to use to get the file...   
    http://123.theserver.net/data/sel_data=*&query_str=lud>'$newdates'&dl_type=file&send_done=no&e=.csv

    .csv  ??

Comment: `Resource id #3` means returned objects as results. Often this errors are exported from XML but, your data is exported from CSV and is convrted to an object. I say XML because this errors code is related on XML exported errors often. Your code are not in XML, but can convert from CSV to XML manually if you want for future transform...

Comment: Thanks Marin!  Ive emailed the data source asking them to ask their tech if they are now on an XML format and also sent my original code. Which they provided me with in 2004.. stating this is how you get our files. I doubt they changed anything as the link itself retrieves the csv and its within seconds. I cannot remember but the data.csv file in my mx folder is 777  writable.. does the folder have to be set to 777 also, or just 765 is ok?.. Im really wondering if my entire site was transferred to another server within the company and the write rules were messed up in the process.

Comment: Set 0755 because you risk your server for outsource accessing (no access from group and public).

Comment: STACK OVERFLOW You can delete this entire thread.. its irrelevant, as the cause was the server itself and not any programming.. even the code
     $newdates = date("Ymd",strtotime(date('Ymj')) - (60 * 24 * 60 * 60));

     works properly again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the URL is being formed correctly.
2. Make sure that the *remote* server is not the one taking forever.
3. Check the load averages on your server. It could be a very slow write due to a severe IO bottleneck.

Also, never ever *ever* say something to your host like "my code worked fine for X years before and now it's broken so it's *your fault*" because that is the exact moment when we stop giving a sh*t. Your code is probably not the problem in this *particular* case, but so many people lob this excuse at us and the fact is that sh*t code can work for years until it hits the asymptote of its efficiency graph and there are just so many levels of not caring... their job is to make sure that the *server* is working, they don't get paid to debug your code for you.

What you *should* be doing is investigating the problem to the best of you abilities, including your findings and supporting evidence in the support ticket, and never once implying that the server ops "must have changed *something*".

Comment: Author says that `Resource id #3` which means is received an XML of data and should parse a data from object to an array and grabbing a data...

Comment: @CraigR wait, what? how did that *ever* work in the first place? `date('Ymj')` returns a **string** [2013037 for today] from which you are subtracting 60 days in seconds 5184000, which is currently -3170963, an invalid timestamp so the default 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT is used. I take back what I said about your code being ok.

Comment: Code is commented, so this is his mistake...
`echo $newdates = date("Ymd", strtotime("-3 months"));`
Result: 20121208

Comment: go put it in a file.. it should read 20121208 ... it does on 5 other hosting companys servers.. but on the server of topic it returns 1969.   echo print it. tell me what your server says. It will help also could tell exactly what the issue with this hosting co's server is ( as they say theyve never changed anything.. but ive never changed my script in 8-10 years). 

     $newdates = date("Ymd",strtotime(date('Ymj')) - (60 * 24 * 60 * 60));

Comment: The moral is... if they said YES we did change stuff on our servers I'd be like great I'll open up my books and start fixin.. but they said theyve done nothing in the past week. So thats worse trouble shooting for everyone!

Comment: Sammitch ...  this problem was solved, It was in fact the server. Slow boggy, and some update changed everything. This is what I LOVE ABOUT server guys. They know everything and nothing all at the same time. Its like you guys could drive a car down a highway lose the entire backend and not even realize it cause your god.  ;)

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you for the insider view on client's blanket dumping of fault on web host. And yes, it is common courtesy also that if you are asking someone for help (even if you are paying), it is better to be humble and willing to resolve an issue. But maybe, lots of clients have been brainwashed that since they are the party which hands over the cash, that they have a right to entitlement.